# Snapping to surface (face) doesn't work as expected

Tags: mesh, snapping

I am new with blender and I am currently following the donut tutorial but I got a little stuck now. I am trying to snap a point to a surface but it just doesn't work.

I have spend a lot of time now trying to fix it but I am running out of things to try. What I have tried so far:

- I took a look at different settings. Snapping to lines did work.
- I rebuilt the top part of the model (model consists out of a part below: donut and a part on top: icing)
- I tried snapping with simple mesh blocks and it didn't work.
- I tried it with and without Xray on.
- I tried with single and multiple points at the same time.
- I restarted the program.

Somebody a clue?

[image: screenshot closeup of vertex not snapping to surface]
[image: screenshot of snapping setting showing face selected]

Comment: Have you tried to move the viewport point of view so that the object/face is behind the vertice that you want to snap? On a straight line of sight. In your screenshot, there is nothing to snap on behind the vertice.

Comment: I thought I had but you are right, that worked. What I dont quite understand is that however my points (I am using proportional editing) snap now, the shape of the Icing moves below the shape of the donut eventually.